# Finding most similar arrays of integers in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

REWRITTEN:

In my project I have images. Each image have 5 tags from range [1,10]. I used Elasticsearch to upload these tags:

I have these documents loaded into elasticsearch in index "my_project" with type "img":

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/my_project/img/1' -d '
 {"tags": [1,4,6,7,9]}
'
```

Other example documents I upload:

```
{"tags": [1,4,6,7]}
{"tags": [2,3,5,6]}
{"tags": [1,2,3,8]}
```

In my application, vectors are much longer, but with fixed number of unique elements. And I have like 20M of these documents.

Now I want to find similar documents for given vector. Vectors are more similar when they have more common tags. So for example I want to find most similar document for integer vector `[1,2,3,7]`. The best match should be last example document `{"tags": [1,2,3,8]}`, since they share 3 common values in their tags, `[1,2,3]`, more common values than with any other vectors.

So here are my problems. If I upload documents with above CURL command, I get this mapping:

```
{
  "my_project" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "img" : {
        "properties" : {
          "tags" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I think that correct mapping should use integers instead of strings. How can I make correct explicit mapping for this type of data?

Now I want to search documents with above similarity algorithm. How can I get 100 most similar documents of above type with similarity algorithm explained above? If I convert these vectors into string with whitespace-separated numbers, I would be able to use boolean query with should statements for this search, but I think that using arrays of integers should be faster. Can you tell me, how can I construct that search query for elasticsearch?

---

### My solution so far

Basic solution I use now is to convert integer array into string. So I save documents as:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/my_project/img/1' -d '
 {"tags": "1 4 6 7 9"}
'
```

and then basically search for string `"1 2 3"`. While this works somehow, I think that it would be more correct and faster to save array of integers as array of integers, not strings. Is it possible to work with arrays of integers in elasticsearch as with arrays of integers? Maybe my approach with strings is best and can't/don't have to use integer arrays explicitly in elasticsearch.

Comment: Define "most similar" -

Comment: By most similar i meant largest intersection between arrays.

Comment: Can you add the mapping for the field "tags"?

Comment: @JohnPetrone I completely rewrite my question. It should be more clear now with all information. Thanks.

Comment: @Ondra Hi, have you got a solution for this? I am facing the exactly same issue like this. Wishing for your response.

Comment: @Michael: unfortunately it was all too slow for me so I have to use another algorithm and data structure.

Comment: @Ondra : Thanks anyway, I currently using the solution you posted. Hope there will be a official usage for this scenario since it's widely asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd take a look at this discussion from last year on the Elasticsearch mailing list from last year. Another ES user was trying to do exactly what you are trying to do, match array elements and sort by similarity. In his case his array members were "one", "two", "three" etc but it's pretty much identical:

http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Similarity-score-in-array-td4041674.html

The problem as noted in the discussion is nothing is going to get you exactly what you want out of the box. Your approach to using the array members (either string or integer, I think both will be fine) will get you close, but will likely have some differences from what you are seeking to achieve. The reason is that the default similarity scoring mechanism in Elasticsearch (and Lucene/Solr too) is TF/IDF: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relevance-intro.html

TF/IDF may be quite close and depending upon use case may give you the same results, but won't be guaranteed to do so. A tag that appears very frequently (let's say "1" had twice the frequency of "2") will change the weighting for each term such that you may not get exactly what you are looking for.

If you need your exact scoring/similarity algorithm I believe you will need to custom score it. As you've discovered a custom scoring script will not scale well as that script is going to be run for each and every document, so it's not too fast to begin with and will decay in response time in a linear fashion.

Personally I'd probably experiment with some of the similarity modules that Elasticsearch provides, like BM25:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-similarity.html

Answer (score 8):

You can achive what you want with a [function score query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) that uses the [Euclidian distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) formula.

Remove you current mapping and index the documments:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/my_project/img/1' -d '
{
    "tags": {
        "tag1": 1,
        "tag2": 4,
        "tag3": 6,
        "tag4": 7
    }
}'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/my_project/img/2' -d '
{
    "tags": {
        "tag1": 2,
        "tag2": 3,
        "tag3": 5,
        "tag4": 6
     }
 }'

 curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/my_project/img/3' -d '
 {
     "tags": {
        "tag1": 1,
        "tag2": 2,
        "tag3": 3,
        "tag4": 8
     }
 }'
```

Stop Elasticsearch and create a script file called 'euclidian_distance.mvel' in `$ES_HOME/config/scripts` and add this script.

```
_score * pow(sqrt(pow(doc['tags.tag1'].value - param1, 2)) + sqrt(pow(doc['tags.tag2'].value - param2, 2)) + sqrt(pow(doc['tags.tag3'].value - param3, 2)) + sqrt(pow(doc['tags.tag4'].value - param4, 2)), -1)
```

Restart Elastisearch and run this query:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/my_project/' -d '
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
         },
         "script_score": {
             "script": "euclidian_distance",
             "params": {
                 "param1": 1,
                 "param2": 2,
                 "param3": 3,
                 "param4": 7
             }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The tags object with the values `1,2,3,8` will be returned first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This solution is correct but very slow. I have 20M documents and scoring function means, that every query would have to go through all documents. My first aproach to convert numeric vector into string and then use normal string search is, I hope, much faster since elasticsearch can use preprocessing into search tree structure.

Comment: I know that this is quite old now, but out of interest, just how slow was it?

Comment: brilliant. if only Elastic would take this, run with it and optimize it as native behavior