# Content-based filtering with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, similarity, content-based-retrieval

I am trying to build a content-based filtering system that classifies products by assigning them features that read like 
`{ salty: 0, sweet: 0.5, bitter: 0.7}`. Which means I give every product a n-dimensional vector, in this case 
`[0, 0.5, 0.7]`.

For a given product I would now like to find "similar" products by calculating the distance between the vectors. So for two products `[0.2, 0.2, 0.8]` and `[0.4, 0.9, 0.9]` the euclidean distance is roughly 0.78, which should be their 'score' (lower is better).

How do I do this with elasticsearch? Is elasticsearch the right tool for such a task?

Note that the real problem has a lot more than 3 dimensions.

Comment: This answer could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24951668/2483542

Comment: And how do you calculate this `distance`? Is it something that can be indexed along with the vector itself?

Comment: I was thinking about plain and simple euclidean distance to find out how close two products are.

Comment: I had one more question in my previous comment. Can you answer that one as well?

Comment: Maybe I don't get it ... how would you index a distance from any query point?

Comment: I edited the question to make it clearer what I want.

Comment: Now I got it. I was thinking at scripting for this. And there is a solution with scripting in the comment from @TroyAndAbed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112482/discussion-between-thorben-bochenek-and-andrei-stefan).

Comment: Ever found a solution to this problem?