# How to combine Elasticsearch function score query and text proximity scoring

Tags: elasticsearch

I'd like to use function score query and text proximity with weight.
But the query does not correctly calcurate score of *"match_phrase"* in *"query.function_score.functions"*

For example, let's say I'm creating curation media and put a banner link of "**Financial articles in 2017**".

I'd like to filter and score like below,

- Filter

  - Articles must be created in 2017.
  - The category must be *"finance"*.
- Scoring

  - The more *"favorite"* articles is, the higher score.
  - If the article has the comment within last 1 month, it gets the higher score.
  - If the article has the certain tags, gets the higher score.

    - (tags might be more than **100+** words)

and data has precondition,

- Precondition

  - the dataset is more than 2 million document
  - articles must have one "category"
  - articles might have one or more "tags"

    - tags might be more than **1000+** in the single article
  - "tags_text" is string text and it is alphabetical order and joined by whitespace

    - ref: [[Finding most similar arrays of integers in elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24945500/finding-most-similar-arrays-of-integers-in-elasticsearch])
  - "favorite" is number that people set the article to "favorite" (e.g. facebook-like button)

### example data and query

```
// create index
$ curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/blog'
```

And put articles,

```
// create articles
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/blog/article/1 -d '
{
  "article_id": 1,
  "title": "Fintech company list in London",
  "tags": ["fintech", "uk", "london"],
  "tags_text": "fintech london uk",
  "category": "finance",
  "created_at": "2016-12-01T00:00:00Z",
  "last_comment_at": null,
  "favorite": 100
}'

curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/blog/article/2 -d '
{
  "article_id": 2,
  "title": "World economy",
  "tags": ["world", "economy", "regression", "war"],
  "tags_text": "economy regression war world",
  "category": "finance",
  "created_at": "2017-02-15T00:00:00Z",
  "last_comment_at": "2017-11-01T00:00:00Z",
  "favorite": 20
}'

curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/blog/article/3 -d '
{
  "article_id": 3,
  "title": "Bitcoin bubble",
  "tags": ["bitcoin", "bubble", "btc", "mtgox", "wizsec"],
  "tags_text": "bitcoin btc bubble mtgox wizsec",
  "category": "finance",
  "created_at": "2017-08-03T00:00:00Z",
  "last_comment_at": null,
  "favorite": 50
}'

curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/blog/article/4 -d '
{
  "article_id": 4,
  "title": "Virtual currency in China",
  "tags": ["bitcoin", "ico", "china"],
  "tags_text": "bitcoin china ico",
  "category": "finance",
  "created_at": "2017-09-03T00:00:00Z",
  "last_comment_at": null,
  "favorite": 10
}'

curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/blog/article/5 -d '
{
  "article_id": 5,
  "title": "Average FX rate in 2017-10",
  "tags": ["fx", "currency", "doller"],
  "tags_text": "currency doller fx",
  "category": "finance",
  "created_at": "2017-11-01T00:00:00Z",
  "last_comment_at": null,
  "favorite": 10
}'

curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/blog/article/6 -d '
{
  "article_id": 6,
  "title": "Cat and Dog",
  "tags": ["pet", "cat", "dog", "family"],
  "tags_text": "cat dog family pet",
  "category": "pet",
  "created_at": "2017-11-02T00:00:00Z",
  "last_comment_at": null,
  "favorite": 500
}'
```

Then execute query,

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/blog/article/_search' -d '
{
  "_source": {
    "includes": ["article_id", "title", "tags_text"]
  },
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "functions": [
        {
          "field_value_factor": {
            "factor": 1,
            "modifier": "log",
            "field": "favorite"
          },
          "weight": 0.3
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "range": {
              "last_comment_at": {
                "from": "now-30d",
                "to": null,
                "include_lower": true,
                "include_upper": false
              }
            }
          },
          "weight": 0.3
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "match_phrase": {
              "tags_text": {
                "query": "bitcoin fintech smartphone",
                "slop": 100
              }
            }
          },
          "weight": 0.4
        }
      ],
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {"term": {"category": "finance"} },
            {
              "range": {
                "created_at": {
                  "from": "2017-01-01T00:00:00",
                  "to": "2017-12-31T23:59:59",
                  "include_lower": true,
                  "include_upper": true
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "must": {
            "match_all": {}
          }
        }
      },
      "score_mode": "sum"
    }
  }
}'
```

The results are like below,

```
{
  "took": 7,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 4,
    "max_score": 0.69030905,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "blog",
        "_type": "article",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.69030905,
        "_source": {
          "article_id": 2,
          "tags_text": "economy regression war world",
          "title": "World economy"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "blog",
        "_type": "article",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.509691,
        "_source": {
          "article_id": 3,
          "tags_text": "bitcoin btc bubble mtgox wizsec",
          "title": "Bitcoin bubble"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "blog",
        "_type": "article",
        "_id": "5",
        "_score": 0.3,
        "_source": {
          "article_id": 5,
          "tags_text": "currency doller fx",
          "title": "Average FX rate in 2017-10"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "blog",
        "_type": "article",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 0.3,
        "_source": {
          "article_id": 4,
          "tags_text": "bitcoin china ico",
          "title": "Virtual currency in China"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I checked result with *"explain"* but it seemed that "match_phrase" query to "tags_text" field does not affect to scoring at all.

How to use weighted similarity scoring and function score query?
(I checked by ES v2.4.0)

Comment: Did you manage to solve it ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I still want to do it, so I'll repost this in ES community forum.

Comment: @HugoLaplace Reposted here https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-combine-elasticsearch-function-score-query-and-text-proximity-scoring-with-weight/163651

Comment: I ended using fuzzy Levenshtein distance on elasticsearch part combined with regexp & keras neural network on app part to solve my particular problem.